# Is a pension considered part of an estate

Tags: united-states, inheritance

I am receiving half of my husband's pension since he died. Is it considered part of his estate? We had a small business which we sold prior to his death, but his sons think the pension I am receiving should be used to pay for his medical bills and the money from the business should be divided between us.

Comment: Depends on (a) the terms of the pension,  and (b) whether the recipient has filled out paperwork saying it should go to their estate or to a particular individual, and (c) the law it's probated under. Plus, of course, whatever the will says. You need to find the relevant paperwork and check what it really adds up to. If the pension was already converted into an annuity, skip all the above and look at the paperwork for the annuity. If necessary, hire a lawyer... but get all the documentation together first.

Answer (score 5):

There are two possible scenarios, relating to slightly different definitions of 'pension'.

The most normal definition of 'pension' is that you are paid a defined amount each week or month by some company, or the government. If so, that is not part of the estate. You won't be able to take it as a lump sum (probably). It isn't affected by whatever your husband wrote in his will.

If, on the other hand, you and your husband had a big sum of money, which you were drawing on to pay your expenses and still are, then the big sum of money would have been part of the estate.

The right person to ask about this is the lawyer who dealt with your husband's will.

None of this is any help in deciding what you should do with the pension.

Comment: And just to offer a bit of tax complexity, a lump sum pension (or 401(k)) can be part of the tax estate, but not the probate estate. If I will all my possessions to public radio, my retirement accounts, with proper beneficiary designations, are not part of those willed asetss.